# How to use XML parameter in Java?

Tags: java, xml, polarion

I have this XML-Code:

```xml
<extension id="free_textfield" label="Description notes" readOnly="true"/>
```

Now I want to add a parameter there like

```xml
<extension id="free_textfield" label="Description notes" readOnly="true" text="sample string maybe with links"/>
```

Now I want to use this text-parameter in my Java class:

```
    public class FormExtensionExample implements IFormExtension {
    public static final String ID = "free_textfield";

    @Inject
    private IDataService service;

    @Override
    public String render(IPObject object, Map<String, String> attributes) {
        
        return null;
    }
```

How can I do this?

Thanks for your help!

Comment: I'm not familiar with the library you're using for this injected class, but presumably if you can use `attributes.get("readOnly")` to retrieve the attribute `readOnly`, you can do the same for `text`.  If it isn't this simple, please explain why in more detail in your question.

Comment: You mean just like:    `public String text = attributes.get("text");` ?
This didnt work. I am using these libraries: package com.polarion.example.formextension;

import java.util.Map;

import javax.inject.Inject;

import com.polarion.alm.tracker.model.ISeverityOpt;
import com.polarion.alm.tracker.model.IWorkItem;
import com.polarion.alm.ui.server.forms.extensions.IFormExtension;
import com.polarion.core.util.EscapeChars;
import com.polarion.platform.persistence.IDataService;
import com.polarion.platform.persistence.model.IPObject;

Comment: Keep in mind that I have little to go on.  I'm not familiar with your library.  However, the way that you currently retrieve `readOnly` attribute should be very similar for retrieving `text` attribute if I'm not mistaken, with exception of the name of the property of course.

Comment: Sorry, forgot to say. I dont use the `readOnly` attribute in my class. It's used directly in the system and idk how. So I need another possibility to get `text`

Comment: You have the code where this attribute is used?  This is what you need to see and learn from.  This is how a good 80% of "how to" problems that programmers get are solved.

Comment: No, I dont have the code where `readOnly` is used. That's the point I tried to figure out, sorry for misunderstanding

Answer (score 0):

Well all attributes that you specify in the Form Configuration like this:

```xml
<extension id="free_textfield" label="Description notes" readOnly="true" text="sample string maybe with links"/>
```

can be found in the `attributes` map parameter of the `render()` method you have to override:

```
@Override
public String render(IPObject object, Map<String, String> attributes) {

    // here you go:
    String myAttributeValue = attributes.get("text");
    // the following will print "sample string maybe with links"
    System.out.println(myAttributeValue);
    
    return null;
}
```